# React: how can I get multiple image size?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object with links

```
const urls = {
  small: https://image1.com,
  medium: https://image2.com,
  large: https://image3.com,
};
```

output should look like that:

```
{
  small: {width: image_width, height: image_height},
  medium: {width: image_width, height: image_height},
  large: {width: image_width, height: image_height}
}
```

I tried like this, but it turns out an infinite loop.
Help me fix my function or show how it is possible in another way

```
const [imageSize, setImageSize] = useState({});

  const getImageSize = () => {
    for (const url in urls) {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = urls[url];
      img.onload = () => {
        setImageSize((prev) => {
          return {
            ...prev,
            [url]: {
              width: img.width,
              height: img.height,
            },
          };
        });
      };
    }
  };
```

Comment: could you please share code how do you call `getImageSize`?

Comment: useEffect(() => {getImageSize()}, [getImageSize]);

Comment: I don't think you need to call the func every time when it's changed, try to do this just on mount `  useEffect(() => {
    getImageSize()
  }, [])`

Comment: but imageSize is empty

Comment: put the possible solution to the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger image `onload` listener it should be mounted to the DOM, otherwise your `setImageSize` not called. To do this you should have valid images and attach it somewhere to the html, like this:

```
  const urls = {
    small: 'https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff',
    medium: 'https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff',
    large: 'https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff',
  }
  
  const getImageSize = () => {
    for (const url in urls) {
      const img = new Image()
      img.src = urls[url]
      img.onload = () => {
        setImageSize(prev => {
          return {
            ...prev,
            [url]: {
              width: img.width,
              height: img.height,
            },
          }
        })
      }
      document.body.appendChild(img)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getImageSize()
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

```
const [imageSize, setImageSize] = useState({});

const urls = {
  small: https://image1.com,
  medium: https://image2.com,
  large: https://image3.com,
}; 

const getImageSize = () => {
 for (const size in urls) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      setImageSize((prev) => {
       return {
        ...prev,
        [size]: {width: this.width, height: this.height}
      }
     })
    };
   img.src = url;
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
 getImageSize()
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

check the fiddle link I hope it will work[https://jsfiddle.net/k7bue0ho/][1]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).